# Is there a way to count the repeating xml tagname and store each on different dictionaries?

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, count

I'm counting the number of times the same tagname exists on XML file. Each block of elements under the same tagname is different from the other in terms of its contents that is why I will save each on different dictionary, array or any data container which can hold the values. The number of dictionary depends on the tagname count value.

Created dictionary, Tagname Search, Count

**XML File**

```
 <Channel>
     <Ch name='1'>
         <Name></Name>
         <Values></Values>
     </Ch>
     <Ch name='2'>
         <Name></Name>
         <Values></Values>
     </Ch>
     <Ch name='3'>
         <Name></Name>
         <Values></Values>
     </Ch>
 </Channel>
```

**Source Code**

```
  //Using dictionary

  Dictionary<string, XmlNodeList> chDictionary = new Dictionary<string, XmlNodeList>
  XmlNodeList chNode = doc.GetElementByTagName("Ch");
  int count = chNode.Count;
  foreach (XmlElement node in chNode)
  {
      chDictionary.Add(node.GetAttribute("Name"), node.ChildNodes);
  }

  //Using Array
  XmlNode[] array
  XmlNodeList chNode = doc.GetElementByTagName("Ch");
  int count = chNode.Count;
  foreach (XmlElement node in chNode)
  {
      array = new List<XmlNode>(Migrate<XmlNode>(node.Attributes("Name"),node.ChildNodes)).ToArray();
  } 
  //Gets the values of the Childnodes only not including the attribute name 
  //of the CH block, then throws it away after the loop. 
  //The last data would be the last CH Block it could find.

  public static IEnumerable<T> Migrate<T>(string v, Systems.Collections.IEnumerable enumerable)
  {
   foreach(object current in enumerable)
    {
      yield return (T) current;
    }
  }
```

Find and count the the CH Tagname
Populate dictionaries based on count number

Comment: What's the question? What problem are you having?

Comment: count the CH tagname and save each block (CH1,2,3) of nodes to dictionaries

Comment: You said *Each block of elements under the same tagname is differen* but then you posted example data where it's all the same! We will find it very hard to work with this lack of consistency in what you say; please post a reliable actual snippet of your xml file

Answer (score 0):

**Sample XML**

```
<Channel>
    <Ch name='1'>
        <Name>CH1</Name>
        <Values>A</Values>
    </Ch>
    <Ch name='2'>
        <Name>CH2</Name>
        <Values>B</Values>
    </Ch>
    <Ch name='3'>
        <Name>CH3</Name>
        <Values>C</Values>
    </Ch>
</Channel>
```

**Code**

I assume that your `Ch` element only contains `Name` as its first element and `Value` as its last element.

If you have more elements beside them, you have to loop through its `ChildNodes` to find those with `Name` property equals to `"Name"` or `"Value"`

Be careful that XML Tag name is case-sensitive, so you must use `"Ch"` instead of `"CH"` when you call `GetElementsByTagName`.

```
Dictionary<string, string> chDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
// I notice that you have "CH" as your element name here
// It should be "Ch" like below
XmlNodeList chNodes = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Ch");

int chCount = chNodes.Count;

foreach (XmlElement chNode in chNodes)
{
    chDictionary.Add(
         chNode.FirstChild.InnerText,
         chNode.LastChild.InnerText);
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Does it produce the result you are expecting ? Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Instead of Dictionary, can I use array of strings to store values??                        Updated my code, please see the changes above~ thanks

Comment: You shouldn't use `Array` because `Array` cannot be resized and we are not certain how many `Ch` tags the XML file may contain. You could add them to a `List<string>` though. It depends on your requirements.

Comment: I've updated my code again. I used a way found on this [ url: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/253048/store-xml-nodelist-in-arraylist ] but I think there is a problem because upon debugging there is no stored data

Comment: Your tag name is `"Ch"`, right ? So you should use `doc.GetElementByTagName("Ch")` instead of `doc.GetElementByTagName("CH")`. Be careful of the uppercase H.

Comment: my bad, it should be CH though

Comment: I've tried using the method of the url above, but after getting the values of a certain CH block, it throws it away and get the another values of the next CH block until it no longer finds any CH block. I need it to be stored in an array.

Comment: Because you are assigning a new `Array` to it every iteration of the loop. I don't think `Array` should be used, we don't know how many `CH` tags your XML file may contain. How about giving my code a try ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't store more than one element in a dictionary for any given key, but you can declare that the value for that key is a storage collection that can store multiple values:

```
//how NOT to store multiple values under one key
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("ch", "one");
dict.Add("ch", "two"); //duplicate key exception
dict["ch"] = "two"; //replaces "one" 

//how to store multiple values under one key
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
if(!dict.ContainsKey("ch"))
  dict.Add("ch", new List<string>());

dict["ch"].Add("one"); //get the list, Add "one" to the list, not the dictionary 
dict["ch"].Add("two");
```

But here youre only selecting one kind of tag (Ch) so why bother with a dictionary at all? Put them in a simple list from the start